# Submit form and show results on same page without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, google-visualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have user submit text in form and AJAX it to enter to db and show up on same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369940/how-to-have-user-submit-text-in-form-and-ajax-it-to-enter-to-db-and-show-up-on-s)

What I want to do:

**index.html** -> form submit to **some.php** -> process data (from index.html)  and send data to **server.php** -> returning results to a index.html div.

I've read ajax, jQuery, I have seen hundreds of questions on this site, but I couldn't figure it out yet.

index.html:

```
<form action="some.php"  method="post">
    Start date: <br/> <input name="idate" id="firstdate" type="text" /><br />
    End date: <br /> <input name="fdate" id="seconddate" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="searchForm" onclick="SubmitForm();" value="Send" />
</form>
```

some.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['data1'] = $_POST['firstdate'];
$_SESSION['data2'] = $_POST['seconddate'];
?>

 function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "server.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);

(...)
```

server.php:

```
$SQLString = "SELECT    
            count(score) as counts,
            DATE(date),
            SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Male,
            SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 2 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Female,
            AVG(age) as age, score
            FROM persons  
            WHERE date > '".$_SESSION['date1']."' AND date < '".$_SESSION['date2']."' 
            GROUP BY DATE(date) 
            ORDER BY DATE(date) asc";   

(...) 
$data[0] = array('day','counts','Male','Female','Age','Score');     
(...)
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Read about ajax here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Learn using AJAX using jQuery. Then just hang an event handler up on form submit event while posting the data to the PHP using AJAX and receiving the reponse that will be displayed. Use Google. Nobody here will write the code and JS for You...

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection!  You cannot trust user input and should never use it to build things like SQL queries.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form id="my_form">
    Start date: <br/> <input name="idate" id="firstdate" type="text" /><br />
    End date: <br /> <input name="fdate" id="seconddate" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="update_div"></div>
```

jquery:

```
var submit_button = $('#submit_form');

submit_button.click(function() {

    var start_date = $('firstdate').val();
    var end_date = $('seconddate').val();

    var data = 'start_date=' + start_date + '&end_date=' + end_date;

    var update_div = $('#update_div');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'proccess_form.php',
        data: data,   
        success:function(html){
           update_div.html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

proccess_form.php:

```
<?php
    $date1 = GET_['start_date'];
    $date2 = GET_['end_date'];

    // PERFORM THE SQL QUERY //
?>
```

Comment: ?start_date=2012&end_date=2014 is what i for those dates, but update_div seems empty :s

Comment: Did you change the sql query like: WHERE date > date1 AND date < date2 ? (no SESSION) Does actually sql return any result?

Answer (score 2):

The process is:

1. Jquery/Javascript function submits the form to a PHP script using AJAX.
2. The PHP scripts does something with the data (no need to call to another PHP! just do it all in one)
3. The PHP script does a `echo` of the info it wants to return to the first HTML page.
4. The first HTML page receives the data from PHP in the callback function of AJAX.